# avoid scrapy revisit on a different run

Tags: python, scrapy

So I have a website I want to crawl periodiacally (let's say once a week)
I want to be able to skip visited URLs to save time and results size etc.

I tried having a dictionary of url unique_ids and a bool, and pickling it to a file but I can't seem to really sync it properly between all the crawlers running.

Anyone has an different idea of how to get it done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Download Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html)**:

---

#### pipelines.py

```
from mybot.utils import connect_url_database

class DedupPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = connect_url_database()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        url = item['url']
        self.db.insert(url)
        yield item
```

#### middlewares.py

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from mybot.utils import connect_url_database

class DedupMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = connect_url_database()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        url = request.url
        if self.db.has(url):
            log.msg('ignore duplicated url: <%s>'%url, level=log.DEBUG)
            raise IgnoreRequest()
```

#### settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'mybot.pipelines.DedupPipeline': 0
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'mybot.middlewares.DedupMiddleware': 0
}
```

Comment: connect_url_database. is it a built-in function?

Comment: @Boaz You need to write this function yourself.